# SQLite Windows 10 RTM universal app

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-10

With the Windows 10 RTM and Visual Studio 2015 RTM SQLite doesn't work any more.

For instance, the tutorial at http://igrali.com/2015/05/01/using-sqlite-in-windows-10-universal-apps/ will not add the SQLLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs files to my project, also the "Microsoft Visual C++ Applocal runtime Package for Windows UAP" reference is not available for me.

The funny thing is it worked with the RC versions ...

SQLite Version:
sqlite-uap-3081101.vsix (5.73 MiB)

Comment: Can't you just add the appropriate assemblies via NuGet? Why are you using a vsix?

Comment: You have to do both, otherwise SQLite will not work.

Comment: My tutorial used the SQLite.Net PCL library which doesn't add the mentioned classes. Did you perhaps try using a different one?

Comment: Hm, originally I have used the sqlite-net package this worked for Win 8/8.1. Obviously I mixed up something ... the PCL package seems to use other namespaces but if I add the 2 classes the compiler, of course, is happy. Your tutorial works! This is a upgrading issue.

Answer (score 3):

Using sqlite-uap-3081101.vsix with VS2015 RTM & the 10240 release of the Windows 10 SDK generates the following warnings:

> The SDK "SQLite.UAP.2015, Version=3.8.11.1" depends on the following 
>   SDK(s) "Microsoft.VCLibs.AppLocal, version=14.0", which have not been 
>   added to the project or were not found.

This is because the SQLite extension is dependent on the AppLocal Runtime Package. In theory the package would be automatically referenced when adding the extension as a reference, however, the package no longer seems to be included in the referenced release of the W10 SDK.

The AppLocal Runtime Package has been replaced with a CRT package like W8 & W8.1 in the release versions of VS2015 + W10 SDK.

If you add a reference to "Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps" your app will build and run although there'll be warnings until the SQLite extension is updated.

Whilst you can just include SQLLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs from SQLite-net directly if you're using nuget to reference a library as per the tutorial then you wont see the files in your project although the classes will be available for you to use.

Answer (score 2):

I think the SQLite team has already fixed the problem.

[SQLite for Universal App Platform](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4913e7d5-96c9-4dde-a1a1-69820d615936) - See Q and A.

[SQLite Timeline](http://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline)

So, just uninstall the existing SDK of SQLite from Visual Studio and install that again. After that I can't see the warning about AppLocal.

Comment: Sadly it's not solved. Also the current version is very unstable using Windows 10 Universal App.