# Windows 10 Universal Javascript app SQLite in Windows Mobile 10

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, winjs, win-universal-app

I currently have a somewhat working Windows 10 Universal app that uses the SQLite wrapper available [here](https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT). The problem however is, when I deploy the app to a Windows 10 Mobile emulator in visual studio, it ceases to work, and instead gives me the following error:

> Exception is about to be caught by JavaScript library code at line
>   401, column 5 in /js/SQLite3.js 0x8007007e - JavaScript runtime error:
>   The specified module could not be found.

As this works fine when deploying to local machine, is there some way I can ensure this works when deploying the UAP app to windows 10 mobile as well? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you add the Sqlite module to your project ?

(under References -> Right click -> add new reference.)